# Form not submitting on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following modal structure containing a form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="by-email" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <small class="waiting"></small>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="/test" method="post" id="form-email">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Cacenl</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-modal btn-send" value="Send">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I am using jQuery to show a "loading gif" once the user submit the form via submit button:

```
$('.btn-send').on('click', function(e){

    /* with this line, I pretend to disable both buttons in order to 
       prevent the user click them while the form is submitted */
    $('.btn-modal').attr('disabled', "disabled");

    /* show the gift image */
    $('.waiting').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

In most browsers it works cool. However in iPad the form is never submitted. According to my debug session this is happening in iPad:

1. Submit button clicked
2. Buttons disabled
3. Loading image showed

Strangely I can make it works in iPad if I remove the line `$('.btn-modal').attr('disabled', "disabled");`, but as consequence buttons are not disabled neither loading is displayed. So, how can I prevent this error in iPad? Thank you in advance

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` in the event handler

Comment: I think that my question is being confused. I do like submit the form in iPad like in other browsers do, but using `e.preventDefault()` just will stop the form to be submitted at all.

Comment: The page will be reloaded on form submit

Comment: @Tushar, I am complety sure that it does not. Tested and confirmed

Comment: After you disable the button add `$("#form-email").submit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the form submit without changing elements that participate in/trigger the submission process. Disable buttons later:

```
$('.btn-send').on('click', function(e){

    setTimeout(function() {
      /* with this line, I pretend to disable both buttons in order to 
         prevent the user click them while the form is submitted */
      $('.btn-modal').attr('disabled', "disabled");

      /* show the gift image */
      $('.waiting').fadeIn('fast');

    }, 1);

});
```

Comment: This works for desktop browsers and now in iPad! But let me say you something very rare. With this code the form is now submitted, but animations are not getting displayed in iPad. Looks like iPad does not support animations after form submitting

Comment: You can experiment with line `$('.waiting').fadeIn('fast');` in and out of `setTimeout`.

Comment: @manix after a standard form submission the browser will navigate -- making your animation irrelevant.

Comment: @Jasen - it is relevant - while browser is waiting for the first byte of the response.

Comment: If you have the opportunity test the code in iPad then try it yourself. Animations are never applied in/our/before/after of setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

The default action of submit button click is to submit the form. In jQuery, you can use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false;` from event handler to prevent the default action from happening.

> The default action for the event will not be triggered

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Your code should look like this

```
$('.btn-send').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.waiting').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Comment: No my friend, I do not want to stop the form to be submitted. I want to make it works iPad. I have updated the question a few works to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

You could submit the form via ajax.  On success, you can disable the button. An example would be:

```
$('.btn-send').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: /test,
        type:'POST',
        data: { 'foo': foo},
        success: function(data) {
              $('.btn-modal').attr('disabled', "disabled");

              /* show the gift image */
              $('.waiting').fadeIn('fast');    
        }
    )};
});
```

You'll probably need to edit this a little but this is the gist.

Comment: Thank you, but I consider unnecessary using Ajax just to disable, visually, both buttons.

Comment: You want to submit the form, but stay on the page and disable the button, correct?

Comment: No, in IPad the form is not submitted, I just wanted to fix it (in Ipad)